# Adding viewpager as a scrolling header in listview

Tags: android

I am trying to add Viewpager (using support library4) in a list header but its not displaying anything. this is my code please help. It will be in list header not as an item so it shouldn't be a problem.

```
public class CustomActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static int NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS = 20;
    private Context cxt;
    private CustomPageAdapter pageAdapter;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String[] items = { "this", "is", "my", "list",    "view", "data" };
        this.cxt = this;

        ViewPager viewPager =  new ViewPager(this);

        pageAdapter = new CustomPageAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        viewPager.requestLayout();

        getListView().addHeaderView(viewPager);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));

    }

    private class CustomPageAdapter extends PagerAdapter{


            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                    return NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
            }

        /**
         * Create the page for the given position.  The adapter is responsible
         * for adding the view to the container given here, although it only
         * must ensure this is done by the time it returns from
         * {@link #finishUpdate()}.
         *
         * @param container The containing View in which the page will be shown.
         * @param position The page position to be instantiated.
         * @return Returns an Object representing the new page.  This does not
         * need to be a View, but can be some other container of the page.
         */
            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
                    TextView tv = new TextView(cxt);
                    tv.setText("Bonjour PAUG " + position);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    tv.setTextSize(20);

                    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(tv,0);

                    return tv;
            }

        /**
         * Remove a page for the given position.  The adapter is responsible
         * for removing the view from its container, although it only must ensure
         * this is done by the time it returns from {@link #finishUpdate()}.
         *
         * @param container The containing View from which the page will be removed.
         * @param position The page position to be removed.
         * @param object The same object that was returned by
         * {@link #instantiateItem(View, int)}.
         */
            @Override
            public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
                    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((TextView) view);
            }



            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                    return view==((TextView)object);
            }


        /**
         * Called when the a change in the shown pages has been completed.  At this
         * point you must ensure that all of the pages have actually been added or
         * removed from the container as appropriate.
         * @param container The containing View which is displaying this adapter's
         * page views.
         */
            @Override
            public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {

            }


            @Override
            public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {

            }

            @Override
            public Parcelable saveState() {
                    return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void startUpdate(View arg0) {

            }

}

}
```

Comment: have you tried using a Activity with a Layout that has ListView then adding ViewPager above the ListView

Comment: @Proxy32 I want view pager in the scrolling header not as a fixed header at top, so i didn't tried that way.

Answer (score 0):

listview header and footer show after setadapter.

if you try setadapter, and cant see viewpager. check viewpager's width and height.

if viewpager's width or height value is 0.
create LienarLayout(or anyViewGroup) and addview viewpager in viewgroup with layoutparame include width and height setting. and addHeader viewgroup.

my english skill not good, if dont understand, add comment me.

i hope help.